# C# Vlc Forms volume stabilization problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vlc, libvlc

I am using Vlc.DotNet.Forms package in my project. I open one video on form. Everything okay. But If I want to open a video again. When I change the volume, the volume of both videos changes.

My Code Example:

---

```
     public VlcControl control;
     public void Player(string url,int volume){         
            this.control = new VlcControl();
            var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;
            var libDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));
            control.BeginInit();
            control.VlcLibDirectory = libDirectory;
            control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            control.EndInit();
            this.Controls.Add(control);
            control.SetMedia(new Uri(@"" + url + ""));
            control.Audio.Volume=volume;
            control.Play();
            }
```

---

For example,

```
    Player("C:\\test\video1.mp4",50);
    Player("C:\\test\video2.mp4",75);
```

The first video opens and the volume becomes 50. Then when I open the second video, the volume of both videos is 75.

I use these packages

- VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows (Version 3.0.0) https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
- Vlc.DotNet.Forms (Version 3.0.0) https://github.com/ZeBobo5

Comment: Are you using 2 mediaplayers for this?

Comment: Yes.Because in the examples on the internet, two libraries were used.  [link](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Using-Vlc.DotNet-in-WinForms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue of libvlc 3.x.

The workaround is to use a different audio output. In Vlc.DotNet, you can do so like this:

```
control.VlcMediaplayerOptions = new []{ "--aout=directsound" };
```

Before `control.EndInit();`.

References:

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=147229

https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/524

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the previous answer did not work for me, instead I used the following:

```
vlcControl.Play();
var directsound = vlcControl.Audio.Outputs.All.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "directsound");
if (directsound != null)
{
    vlcControl.Audio.Outputs.Current = directsound;
    vlcControl.Audio.IsMute = true;
}
```

Setting the directsound just after having started the player.
You can then toggle mute with:

```
vlcControl.Audio.ToggleMute();
```

Setting the volume is similar with:

```
vlcControl.Audio.Volume = 50;
```